# Android Out Of Memory error with 20MB text file in HashMap

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

(Beginner Android Question: )
I'm loading a 25MB thesaurus text file into a HashMap but I get an Out Of Memory Fatal Exception. I have researched this site to find ideas on other ways to do this but am still unsure.
Would it be sensible to split the text file into a number of smaller ones (say 26, one for each letter) , and then read these from text file to HashMap as needed by the program ? Are there better ways to do this ?
The app is meant to show all the synonyms for words inputted by the user.

```
12-23 13:04:44.336: E/AndroidRuntime(9865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 13:04:44.336: E/AndroidRuntime(9865): Process: com.example.dictfromtextfile, PID: 9865
12-23 13:04:44.336: E/AndroidRuntime(9865): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6532 byte allocation with 4262 free bytes and 4KB until OOM
12-23 13:04:44.336: E/AndroidRuntime(9865):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95
```

Comment: Why not use a database, and query the database for synonyms?

Comment: I think you've reached max limit of android apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675557/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-an-app-can-use

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll try loading the text file into an SQLite database and see if that works better,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the entire file into memory at once is highly not recommended and will throw you an `OutOfMemoryException` error depending on the device you're using. You can use a SQLite database to store your data and perform database actions on it to search, insert or remove data.

In case you wish to store your data in a text file, you can use a `BufferedReader` to read the file line by line  using the `readLine()` method (loading each line into the memory only when it's needed). You can then wrap it with a class of your own to enable all the features you need, like searching.