# What is the normal memory-ram size?(xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using an application with many activities inside. also listview with images and so on. Here is an image from apk.
      Here is an image[image: Analyzer]

First question what kind of memory is this with red circle? Is it Ram? Or heap memory?
Second question what is the normal size for each apk.Is it safe bigger than a number of memory?
Third question my application if this memory is above 380mb. In some cases it crashes my apk.with error message apk doesnt respond. Is something which i can do for this?
Most common activity uses a listview with items inside:Here is part of my code:
I'm using very much sqlite in my apk.

```
var table = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>(
    "select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + 
    Connection.CategoryID + " and InventoryItemName like '%" + 
    etSearchAlwaysOn.Text.ToUpper() + "%'");

mItems = new List<InventoryPreviewClass>();

foreach(var item in table)
{
    mItems.Add(new InventoryPreviewClass() { 
        InventoryItemID = item.InventoryItemID, 
        InventoryItemName = item.InventoryItemName, 
        InventoryItemPrice = item.InventoryItemPrice 
    });
}

MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
```

I tag also java cause its similar

Comment: Are your getting an `ANR` reported by Android? What is reported in Logcat when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First question what kind of memory is this with red circle? Is it Ram? Or heap memory?

**Working Set** : refers to the total physical memory (RAM) used by the process.  For more detail information you could refer to : [What is private bytes, virtual bytes, working set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set)

> Second question what is the normal size for each apk. Is it safe bigger than a number of memory?

Android provide [MemoryClass on ActiviyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) API to get the value for your device, for deatail information, you could refer to : [What is the maximum amount of RAM an app can use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675557/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-an-app-can-use)

> Third question my application if this memory is above 380mb. In some cases it crashes my apk.

As you said, your application has `ListView` with images and in some cases it crashes your apk, when you app load many image at one time it will occupy lots of memory, and it usual cause `OutOfMemoryError`, so I think your problem is an [OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). **You should pay more attention to the heap size in your app instead of the `Working Set`**. As the Android [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html) said :

> To allow multiple running processes, Android sets a hard limit on the heap size alloted for each app. **The exact heap size limit varies between devices based on how much RAM the device has available overall.** If your app has reached the heap capacity and tries to allocate more memory, the system throws an OutOfMemoryError.

Since we don't know how did you load images to your listview, here are some suggestion :

- 1. It is recommend to implement image cache, but there is no need to reinvent the wheel, focus on the core logic of your app instead. **Just use a known and solid framework for Cache & Fetching images**, like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Then you can use it to load image in your `listview` like this:

     ```
     Picasso.With(context).Load(imageUrl).Into(imageView);
     ```
- 2. Try to implement [View Holder Pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) to increases the performance `ListViews`. Xamrin.Android example [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/).
- 3. Make sure there is no memory leak in your Application.